# Configuration problem: spring-security-web classes are not available. You need these to use <filter-chain-map>

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit4

I am attempting to run some unit tests on my spring web app using Maven. The app installs and runs fine, it generates a deployable war file all OK (all using Maven).

My test class (located in src/test/java):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:C:/myProjects/myWebapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-test.xml"})
@Transactional
public class MyTest {
...
```

However I recieve the error :

```
Configuration problem: spring-security-web classes are not available. You need these to use <filter-chain-map>

Offending resource: URL [file:C:/myProjects/myWebapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-test.xml]
```

When running `Maven > test`

My pom dependcy is defined as

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
<version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>                
</dependency>
```

Which defaults to `compile` scope, [which should be OK](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) ?  It returns the same error when I change scope to `test` and `provided`.

And my `.classpath` looks like this:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources"/>
```

How do I set-up my app context and tests correctly ?

Comment: Sounds like a classpath issue.  Have you included all the required Spring dependencies in your `pom.xml`, with the appropriate `scope` level to ensure that Maven includes them on your classpath during the test phase?

Comment: well I thought I did, will edit question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to include the Servlet library in your pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>{version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar problem and that was the solution (org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy imports a few javx.servlet classes)

Answer (score 13):

It's a [bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1455) of Spring Security. Include Spring Security Web to your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```