# Running tests using maven displays classpath problems

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I am attempting to run some unit tests on my spring web app using Maven. The app installs and runs fine without tests.

I receive this error in my surefire test report :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletException
```

The test itself looks like this  :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:C:/myProjects/myWebapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-test.xml"})
@Transactional
public class MyTest {
...
```

Previously I was receiving this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402144/configuration-problem-spring-security-web-classes-are-not-available-you-need-th), however I removed any reference to the security package from test app context. And got this latest error.

Both problems are caused by my classpath not being set correctly ? The maven dependencies do not seem to be included when testing ?  How can I change this, or what else am I missing ?

Comment: Can you post your pom? Sounds like you're missing the servlet-api as a `<provided>` scoped artifact.

Comment: I assume the javax.servlet.ServletException is included someone in your import-packages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Your servlet container will have this but some of your tests must need it. You may need to adjust the version.

The scope is important. You don't want to bundle this jar into your war but you want it available to your tests.

Comment: I've always seen the servlet apis get mocked rather than included in test scope

Comment: Kevin, you still need the API on the classpath to be able to mock it, which is what this does.